# Unity 2D : Does having smaller sprite size improve performance?

Tags: android, performance, 2d, sprite

I have recently started working on a 2d project in unity 2d it's aimed at android/ios devices.

I have loads of sprites that need to be displayed at once on one screen and I can use one of the following sizes 256x256, 128x128, 32x32.

is using smaller sprite size help improve performance?

Comment: For such small buffer sizes the main bottleneck would probably be draw-call latency

Comment: do you mean that the smaller the sprites the lower the performance? please explain if you can

Comment: No, I mean that for such small sprites their size isn't a major factor in determining the performance (unless you are running on very old hardware)

Comment: now I get the point thanks!